# what is the correct international mobile phone number format for UK-based iphones

Tags: iphone, contacts

A while back my iPhone would not dial mobile phone numbers correctly.  The problem seemed to be that the '07' at the start of the UK mobile code was identified by the phone as being a country code.  At the time this problem was solved by adding '+44' to mobile numbers in my address book which created this format (which worked).

> +44 (0) 7xxx xxx xxx

Fast forward to today and I am having trouble again with mobile numbers.  And the solution seems to be to keep the country code (+44) but remove the zero that begins the mobile number:

> +44 7xxx xxx xxx

I have tried to find confirmation of this and failed.  Can someone explain the rules for storing phone numbers on my iPhone (iOS 15.2.1).

Also, are the formatting rules the same for landline numbers?

Comment: The +44 (0) 7xxx xxx xxx has never been an approved standard - but just what some people wrote. All my iPhone numbers have always been in the last format

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both.

Drop the leading 0 and put 0044 in front or +44

Have landline and family with +44 and the number with the leading 0 dropped.

About 70 different numbers but not showing any.

Lots of sites show that info, this is but one:
[enter link description here](https://www.visitnorthwest.com/essential/uk-telephone-numbers/)

Comment: Thanks.  So... can I store all my contact numbers - landline and mobile - in the international format.  So landline 0117 xxx xxxx as +44 117 xxx xxx; and mobile 07788 xxx xxx as +44 7788 xxx xxx ?

Comment: (also, I don't understand your penultimate line "About 70...")

Comment: About 70 means I have some 70 numbers for the UK stored in the correct format. Not only UK I have numbers for France and Germany that work as well.

Comment: 0044 is for landlines without a + key. +44 is for mobiles. Drop the leading zero from the ’area’ code in both cases.

Comment: +44 means the country code is 44=UK, and your phone will dial the correct number according to where you are. Inside the UK it dials 0.  From Germany it dials 0044. In another country it might dial something else ending in 44, because every country can have different rules how to dial another country.